# How do I parallely check for existence of an item across multiple lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7, python-3.x

As a part of my project, for every word in the dictionary d (shown in the example code snippet below), I need to check for its existence across different lists `f1, f2, f3`. I have shown only 3 lists here. And based on the occurrence, I need to calculate two output values(rule inputs and weights). The problem I am facing here is, the word can occur in any number of lists, say word1 in dict d occurs in lists `f1, f2, f3` (shown below) and word2 in dict d occurs in f1 and f2 and word3 occurs only in one list f3. I have 100s of these individual lists. I need an efficient and straight forward method to calculate output values(rule inputs and weights) for every word in dictionary d based on their varying occurrences across these lists, so that I don't have to check for every combination of occurrence and write a separate condition for it, which would make things complicated and ugly.

**P.S.:** The lists are of different size. In example below, f1, f2 and f3 are of different sizes.

**My Code:**

```
import itertools

d = {'Rosa': 0.023, 'code': 0.356, 'Syntel': 0.144, 'Robotics': 0.245, 'Web': .134, 'sanskrit': 0.23, 'Tamil': 0.23}
f1 = [['Syntel', 0.2, 4, 0.46, 7, 0.9], ['code', 0.45, 9, 0.43, 2, 0.23], ['Robotics', .43, 3, .1, 3, .73]]
f2 = [['Web', 0.5, 5, 0.06, 6, 0.9], ['code', 0.05, 1, 0.28, 2, 0.73]]
f3 = [['Web', 0.5, 5, 0.06, 6, 0.9], ['sanskrit', 0.05, 1, 0.28, 2, 0.73], ['Tamil', 0.23, 4, .13, 5, .23], ['code', 0.32, 4, 0.12, 4, .24]]

# specific case where I am checking if a word of the dictionary occurs in all of the lists f1, f2 and f3
# I have to write chunk of code for every possible combo of occurrence which I think is a bad approach
# I am brain stuck ! Help please !!
for word, score in d.iteritems():
    for x in f1:
        if word == x[0]:
            for y in f2:
                if word == y[0]:
                    for z in f3:
                        if word == z[0]:
                            A = x[2] * x[3]
                            B = x[4] * x[5]
                            C = y[2] * y[3] + 1
                            D = y[4] * y[5] + 1
                            E = z[2] * z[3] + 1
                            F = z[4] * z[5] + 1
                            mfs = [[A, B], [C, D], [E, F]]
                            weights = sum([x[3], x[5], y[3], y[5], z[3], z[5]])
                            rule_inputs = list(itertools.product(*mfs))
                            len_comb = len(rule_inputs)
                            # 6 --> need code to find this automatically
                            weight_factor = (len(mfs) * len_comb) / 6
                            weights *= weight_factor
                            rule_inputs = sum([sum(r) for r in rule_inputs])
                            print word, rule_inputs, weights
```

Comment: I get the sense that maybe storing the data as a list of lists may not be the best form. Have you considered using a `dict` instead. Say, `f1 = {'Word1': [1, 2, 3], 'Word2': [3, 4, 5]}`, for example?

Comment: +1 @JoelCornett. And even if you need the `list`s for some other reason, it's still probably both most efficient and simplest to build a `dict` for each `list` anyway: `d1 = {elem[0]: elem[1:] for elem in f1}`.

Comment: One thing: In your sample data, the same name never appears twice in any list. Is that guaranteed  to be true, or is it possible that `f3[0][0]` and `f3[55][0]` could both be `'Web'`? If that can happen, you actually need either some kind of "multidict" structure, or a dict mapping keys to lists of values, instead of just to values.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, the same name never appears twice. The list contains unique entries only.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: OK, cool, that makes things simpler—and means my answer isn't wrong (after all that typing). :)

Comment: @abarnert Thanks! for your valuable input. I am rewriting code as per your suggestion using dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joel Cornett says, you probably should be using `dict`s rather than `list`s in the first place.

But if you need the `list`s for some reason… well, if you're going to search through a `list` multiple times, you probably want to build a `dict` to search through:

```
d1 = {elem[0]: elem for elem in f1}
```

Then, instead of this:

```
for z in f3:
    if word == z[0]:
```

… you can just do this:

```
z = d3.get(word)
if z is not None:
```

You may also want to follow EAFTP and just `try` the whole thing. Your whole loop then looks  like this:

```
for word, score in d.iteritems():
    try:
        x, y, z = d1[word], d2[word], d3[word]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    A = x[2] * x[3]
    # etc.
```

This is assuming you specifically need three lists, as opposed to an arbitrary number. If you needed to be able to work with any number of lists, you'd do this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{elem[0]: elem for elem in lst} for lst in list_of_lists]
for word, score in d.iteritems():
    try:
        values = [d[word] for d in list_of_dicts]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    A = values[0][2] * values[0][3]
    # etc.
```

---

There are a few alternatives to this, but this is probably the one you want.

You can `sort` each list and use `bisect` instead of an iterative linear search, or use something like [`SortedCollection`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) to wrap that up for you, or [`blist.sortedlist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) for a similar type. This makes the search O(log N) instead of O(N), and makes the code simpler. But a `dict` makes the search O(1) instead of O(N), and makes the code exactly as simple as using a sorted list, so, unless you're dealing with keys that are not hashable (and you're not), why bother?

You can also wrap up the `for`/`if` by writing a `find_in_list` function, which gives you the same simplicity as a `dict` or `sortedlist`, but without the performance gains. This could be useful if the keys are neither hashable nor orderable, or if you had a huge number of tiny lists (so tiny that a linear search is actually faster than a dict or tree lookup—maybe around size 2-3?). But otherwise, you're just doing extra work (to write the `find_in_list` wrapper) to slow yourself down, so again, why bother?

Comment: +1. I'm not 100% sure, but I think OP wants to be able to extend this to more than 3 lists. In that case, the test would be something like: `all(word in d for d in list_of_dicts)`.

Comment: @JoelCornett: I don't think so. Look at the logic in his code: he's assigning the found values to `x`, `y`, and `z`, and doing arithmetic specifically on `x[2]`, `z[5]`, etc. So, first, he doesn't just need the test, he definitely needs the values. (Which would be `values = [d[word] for d in list_of_dicts]`.) But second, he seems to pretty explicitly need three lists, not an arbitrary number. But… future readers with similar problems might want an arbitrary number, so I'll update the answer, and +1 for bringing it up.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Take look on mapreduce library
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview